# Ansible through Apache: Authentication or permission failure

Tags: python, ansible

I try run Ansible through Apache2 CGI.

This is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-# enable debugging
print "Content-type: text/html"
print

import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
print "<html><head>"
print ""
print "</head><body>"

import os
import ansible.runner
import sys
results = ansible.runner.Runner(
#    transport='ssh',
#    remote_user='root',
#    remote_pass='pass',
    transport='local',
#    su='yes',
#    su_user='root',
#    su_pass='su_pass',
    sudo='yes',
    sudo_user='root',
    sudo_pass='sudo_pass',
    pattern='127.0.0.1',
    module_name='service',
    module_args='name=shoc-lxc-net state=started enabled=yes',
    forks=10,
).run()

if results is None:
   print "No hosts found"
   sys.exit(1)

import json
print(json.dumps(results,
                 default=lambda obj: vars(obj),
                 indent=1))

for (hostname, result) in results['contacted'].items():
    if not 'failed' in result:
        print "%s >>> %s" % (hostname, result['enabled'])

print "</body></html>"
```

When I run it, I get:

> { "dark": { "127.0.0.1":  { "msg": "Authentication or permission
>   failure. In some cases, you may have been able to authenticate and did
>   not have permissions on the remote directory. Consider changing the
>   remote temp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\". Failed
>   command was: mkdir -p
>   $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-1420984254.94-125323999727459 && chmod a+rx
>   $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-1420984254.94-125323999727459 && echo
>   $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-1420984254.94-125323999727459, exited with
>   result 1",  "failed": true } }, "contacted": {} }

But when I run this script through shell I get:

```
$ /lxc/www/py/index.py 
Content-type: text/html

<html><head> </head><body> {  "dark": {},  "contacted": {  
"127.0.0.1": {    "invocation": {
    "module_name": "service",
    "module_args": "name=shoc-lxc-net state=started enabled=yes"    },    "state": "started",    "changed": false,    "enabled": true,   
"name": "shoc-lxc-net"   }  } }
127.0.0.1 >>> True
```

When I check:

```
# ls -la /var/www/
total 20
drwxrwxrwx  4 root     root     4096 Jan 11 15:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root     root     4096 Jan  8 15:58 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root     4096 Jan 11 14:54 etc
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root      177 Mar 18  2013 index.html
drwx------  2 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 11 15:36 .ssh
# su www-data
$ mkdir /var/www/.ansible/tmp -p
$
# ls -la /var/www/.ansible/
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 11 15:57 .
drwxrwxrwx 5 root     root     4096 Jan 11 15:57 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 11 15:57 tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

The script is going to run as the apache user (or whatever user you are running apache as - in some cases that may be 'nobody' or something else entirely). That user most likely doesn't have the same permissions as you.  You would likely need to either [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) the script to run as a user with the appropriate permissions or add an entry to /etc/sudoers to allow the script to run as a different user without prompting for a password then use a wrapper shell script to have Apache invoke the script via [sudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo).

Comment: if I change temp dir into ansible.cfg(tmp = $HOME/.ansible/tmp
) to tmp=/tmp it's work. but I cant' do this on my servers

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when running my Ansible project in Molecule. Here's what I found:

When running the command `molecule test --destroy=never` I reproduce the very same issue with the tmp folder/files. If I skip the `destroy` flag and just run `molecule test` -- it works fine.

Posting this answer as folks in the community might run into this issue. As a workaround, you can `Ctrl+C` after molecule is done with the `verify` step, just before it finishes execution -- a.k.a `destroy`

Molecule steps:

```
└── default
    ├── lint
    ├── destroy
    ├── dependency
    ├── syntax
    ├── create
    ├── prepare
    ├── converge
    ├── idempotence
    ├── side_effect
    ├── verify
    └── destroy
```